# No muestra los resultados en mi datatables en angular

Tags: angular, datatables, angular5, angular-datatables

Siguiendo ***[este ejemplo](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/row-click-event)***:

**categoria.component.html**

```html
<blockquote>Please click on a row</blockquote>
<p class="text-danger">You clicked on: <strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>
<br />
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

**categoria.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

import { CategoriaService } from '../services/categoria.service';
import { Categoria } from '../models/categoria';

class DataTablesResponse {
  data: any[];
  draw: number;
  recordsFiltered: number;
  recordsTotal: number;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-categoria',
    templateUrl: '../views/categoria.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../styles/categoria.component.css'],
  providers: [CategoriaService]
})
export class CategoriaComponent implements OnInit {

  message = '';
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  public id;
  public categoria: Categoria[];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ){
  }

  someClickHandler(info: any): void {
    this.message = info.id + ' - ' + info.nombre;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const that = this;

    this.dtOptions = {
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        that.http
          .post(
            'http://localhost/webapp-backend/index.php/categorias/listar',
            dataTablesParameters, {}
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            that.categoria = resp.data;
            console.log(resp.data.length);
            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.data.length,
              recordsFiltered: resp.data.length,
              data: []
            });
          });
      }, 
      columns: [
        {
          searchable: false,
          orderable: false,
          title: 'N°',
          data: 'id'
        },
        {
          title: 'Nombre',
          data: 'nombre'
        },
        {
          searchable: false,
          title: 'Estado',
          data: 'status'
        }
      ],
      order: [[1, 'asc']],
      rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
        const self = this;
        $('td', row).unbind('click');
        $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
          self.someClickHandler(data);
        });
        return row;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

El resultado que obtengo de la url es el siguiente:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "code": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "nombre": "jardin",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "nombre": "ciudad",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "nombre": "flores",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "nombre": "fantasia",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "nombre": "Espacio",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "nombre": "Tela",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "nombre": "Cultura",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "nombre": "Pais",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 26,
      "nombre": "Hogar",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "nombre": "Zapatos",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "nombre": "Pantalones",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 29,
      "nombre": "Insigneas",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "nombre": "Cuadros",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "nombre": "Baño",
      "status": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Y la tabla que obtengo es la siguiente (ningún dato):
[image: Tabla]

Comment: ¿resp.draw no debería ser resp.data? No hay ningún campo draw en la respuesta

Comment: @PabloLozano disculpa, fue un error mientras ordenaba el código para publicarlo. Ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Pudieras utilizar [este componente](https://www.uno-de-piera.com/angular-4-y-datatables/) está muy bien explicado su uso

Comment: Podría estar pasando que el servicio no esté funcionando correctamente, si lo que vas a hacer es solo obtener información tu petición deberia ser GET y no POST, ya intentaste hacer una prueba con postman ?

Comment: @LordOfLies si, en postman me funciona correctamente y el enlace también, de hecho en la pregunta coloco el resultado de la url.

Comment: Estás siguiendo un ejemplo ? de ser así podrías indicar cual para darle una revisada

Comment: Esta al principio de la pregunta, de igual forma aca esta de nuevo: [***link***](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/row-click-event)

Comment: Ya probaste haciendo return resp.data; ?

Comment: Otra duda: ¿qué te dice la consola del navegador?